Will asynchronous loading of shopify pages cause inaccurate data in GTM statistics?
I ran into a problem where the code I wrote on the front end of shopify by hardcoding it was not the same as the code I wrote on the web page through the GTM trigger, and the events I ended up counting were not the same
I tried to change my GTM trigger and change it to the same as my front-end code, this is my trigger .
I tried comparing three days of data, but in fact, GTM consistently got about 10 percent less data than the event data I got in my front-end code.
Can someone tell me what is the reason for this situation, is it because of shopify's asynchronous loading mechanism, so the GTM trigger does not trigger the event, but the front-end code can trigger?
However,When I tested the GTM preview mode, if I scrolled to the bottom of the page before it was loaded, all the image exposure events above would not be triggered. Is there any way to fix this?
Here's part of my front-end code:
// banner
DataMonitor['handleBanners'] = function(){
  let images = document.querySelectorAll('.hero__image');
  images = Array.prototype.slice.call(images);
  let ScreenWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
  if(ScreenWidth < 769){
    images = images.filter(item => (item.className.indexOf('medium-up--hide')>-1))
  }else{
    images = images.filter(item => (item.className.indexOf('small--hide')>-1))
  }
  for(let i = 0; i < images.length; i++){
    let image = images[i];
    let ImageWrapper = image.parentNode, 
      ImageInner = image.parentNode;
    while(ImageWrapper.id.indexOf('Slideshow') == -1){
      ImageWrapper = ImageWrapper.parentNode;
      if(ImageWrapper&&ImageWrapper.id==='MainContent')break;
    }
    while(ImageInner.className.indexOf('slideshow__slide')==-1){
      ImageInner = ImageInner.parentNode;
      if(ImageInner&&ImageInner.id==='MainContent')break;
    }
    let id  = ImageWrapper.id.split('-').pop(),
      speed = ImageWrapper.dataset.speed,  
      image_id = ImageInner.dataset.id, event = 'ItemValidView',
      type = 'banner', url = image.src;


If it is a 10% difference. Looks quite normal since the GA4 data's gap is around 5 to 1x% every where. The main reason is the ad blocker that will cause GA4 can not get the data. If you really care about the gap. You can try server side tagging for GA4.
